# c# winforms ошибка System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "Класс не зарегистрирован

Tags: c#

есть исходник приложение winforms, написанный в vs 2013. фраймворк скорее всего 3.5, пытаюсь открывать в vs 2017, NET Framework 4.6 при запуске выдает ошибку. возможно ошибка не из за фреймворка, а из-за сторонней библиотеки ZKFPEngXСontrol . помогите разобраться никак не могу найти решение. исключение вот тут возникает,
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ZKFPEngX1)).EndInit();
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и еще ссылка светит с предупреждением
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

свойства ссылки ZKFPEngXСontrol
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `и еще ссылка светит с предупреждением` - с каким..?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, на второй фотографий видно желтый знак

Comment: Знак - это иконка, а не предупреждение. наведите на него и там должен быть текст того, что именно не нравится.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , там подсказка не высвечивается, картину свойства ссылки выложил выше , посмотрите пожалуйста может что-то подскажет.

Comment: Скорее всего это означает, что библиотека несовместима с указанной версией фреймворка. А исключение о том, что библиотека не смогла проинициализировать своё состояние. Вообще ActiveX - мёртвая технология. Попробуйте оставить проект на 3.5, убедитесь, что у вас установлены компоненты .NET Framework 3.5 SDK в студии.

Comment: @aepot, проверил и с net 3.5 , все равно такая ошибка .заметил что  этой библиотеки нету в исходниках , тоесть в свойствах нет пути к DLL.  какое может быть решение ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42876583/12888024 в тему, возможно надо от COM  уйти на обычный интероп. Тогда сможете без проблем и фреймворк поменять и приложение обновить. Но сначала конечно же стоит заставить работать то что есть.

Comment: Еще вариант "класс не зарегистрирован" может означать, что ОС ничего не знает о библиотеке. Узнайте как ее зарегать в ОС regsvr32.exe или установка драйвера нужна.

Comment: @aepot, после установки драйвера вроде исчезла эта ошибка , теперь возникла другая ошибка ,  Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Interop.ZKFPEngXControl, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей что можете посоветовать насчет этого ?

Comment: Без понятия, библиотека либо несовместима, либо отсутствует. Быть может нужна другая версия драйвера, быть может еще что-то.

Comment: @aepot, приложение в vs  запускается только под x86 , если сделать Any CPU выдает ошибку , у меня процессор на х64 , это значить эта библиотека работает только под х86 ? в NuGet других версий нету

Comment: Запускайте как x86, не вижу проблемы.